# trace.zip file content cannot be opened in instrument

Tags: java, performance-testing, appium-ios

I launched a performance test with an ios app using time profiler instrument
after getting  back instruments `trace.zip`  file
the trace file inside `run.zip` cannot be opened
Could someone have faced this problem before

My code

```
public void testAppActivity() throws Exception {

    try {
        HashMap<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
        args.put("timeout", 60000);
        args.put("pid", "current");
        args.put("profileName", "Time Profiler");
        driver.executeScript("mobile: startPerfRecord", args);

        testchannelnumbers(driver);
        OpenChannelDeviceOne(driver);
        PTT(driver);


        args = new HashMap<>();
        args.put("profileName", "Time Profiler");
        String b64Zip = (String)driver.executeScript("mobile: stopPerfRecord", args);
        byte[] bytesZip = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(b64Zip);
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(traceZip);
        stream.write(bytesZip);
        stream.close();
    } finally {
        driver.quit();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok , it was appium bug related to extracting the zip
a workaround :
Simply extract the unpacked content into a folder and rename that folder to "<your_name>.trace".